# How to Export gRPC Collection in Postman?

Tags: postman

I want to export a gRPC Collection. How can I do it? Unfortunately, there isn't an option to do this in Postman.
Is there an alternative method to export the gRPC collection? Any suggestions for other applications that can do this.

[image]

Comment: Not possible, yet. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11252